# fluent nhibernate convention : setting polymorphism mode

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Is it possible to create a simple convention to modify the polymorphism mode of a class, if there is a joined-subclass ?

Doing this :

```
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<EntityBase>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        Polymorphism.Explicit();
    }
}
```

but inside a convention. Using IClassConvention doesn't work, as the Polymorphism property is read only :

```
public class TestConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        // read only property !
        instance.Polymorphism = Polymorphism.Explicit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
instance.Polymorphism.Explicit();
```

Comment: I believe it depends on how you map your datamodel. AFAIK polymorphism doesn't work with `ClassMap<T>` (joined-subclass).