# Is (n)Hibernate suitable for a model layer with more than 200 classes arranged in a hierarchy?

Tags: database, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My model layer has a pretty huge class hierarchy i.e. there are around 200 classes. The good/bad thing with the hierarchy is that all of them have the same base class (I am not talking about Object class here). The maximum distance between the base and leaf classes is 7 and the maximum number classes at any level in hierarchy is 80. I am using nHibernate to save/load data from persistent storage.

Problem The queries generated by nHibernate are pretty in efficient. The reason being that it tries to join tables that are not really needed in the query?

Has anyone used (n)Hibernate with such class hierarchy?

Please refer to [NHibernate: Load base class objects only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740666/nhibernate-load-base-class-objects-only) to see a specific example of one my problems.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate has to resort to that monster of a query because it did not know exactly which table contains the needed data. For example, with `session.Get<Vehicle>(100)`, NHibernate does not know which table contains the data for the vehicle with ID 100, so it will have to join Vehicle, Car, Truck, Bicycle together. But with `session.Get<Truck>`(100), NHibernate know that data can only resided in Truck table, so the query will be much more efficient, with only one join: Vehicle and Truck.

So, if you cannot change your database schema, then I think you have only one option, namely trying to be as specific as possible when querying by always give NHibernate the exact type of entity you need.

If you can change your schema, then I think you should try to simplify the model classes, avoid such a large inheritance tree. NHibernate provides many other options to connect classes together.

Other option is to use One-to-one instead of joined-subclass to separate information of one domain model class into multiple classes without forcing them to inherit from each other. I have encountered the same problem with a much smaller inheritance tree (about 20 classes out of 150 classes share the same base class, and mapped using joined-subclass). When the family reaches 20-strong, I'm stop adding more class into the hierarchy if that's possible, and try to use One-to-One instead.

Comment: Hi Doan, thanks for your feeback! But I am definitely missing something here...
Can you please point to some helping material on the internet for the One-to-one option. The confusion that I have is if I want to keep inheritance in my domain model but am allowed to modify the mappings, what will be my mappings be? i.e.for a model with one base class and three derived classes? According to Ayende's blog (nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one), one-to-one will work if one row in a table A maps to one row in table B and will not work if one row in a table A might map to a row in either table B or table C?

Comment: If you cannot also change your classes then I cannot think of any other way. With me, I could do that. In my project, the solution for this was from the the observation that `one-to-one` with `foreign` id generation strategy has exactly the same database structure with `joined-subclass` inheritance mapping. For example, class B extends A, using `joined-subclass` will produce exactly the same database table structure with the case where A has a `one-to-one` property of type B. With this, you can change some inheritance into composition. "Favour composition over inheritance" in essential.