# Query only base class

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Having the following structure:

- `Article : IArticle`
- `SuperArticle : Article`
- `AwesomeArticle : Article`

`Article` is not abstract, some items are just articles, other are derived types. Here's my NHibernate config, following table-per-hierarchy strategy (because subclases are also on the main table, and may or may not contain aditional data in other tables):

```
<class name="IArticle" table="Articles" >
<id name="Id" column="IdArticle"/>
 <discriminator type="string" formula="(CASE WHEN IdTipoDef LIKE 'DefProd8' THEN 'SUPER' ELSE CASE WHEN IdTipoDef LIKE 'DefProd9' THEN 'AWESOME' ELSE  'ARTICLE' END END)"/>
<property name="Description" column="Descrip"/>
<subclass name="SuperArticle" discriminator-value="SUPER">
    <join table="otherTable">
        ...
    </join>
</subclass>
<subclass name="AwesomeArticle" discriminator-value="AWESOME">
    <join table="otherOtherTable">
      ...
    </join>
</subclass>
<subclass name="Article" discriminator-value="ARTICLE">
</subclass>
</class>
```

The problem is when I try to query the ones that are just `Article`, that it returns also its subclasses, and if I try to count I get an error:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void EncuentraArticulosTest()
    {
        ISession session = NHibernateHelper.GetSession();
        session.BeginTransaction();
        Debug.Write(session.QueryOver<Article>().Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(Article)).RowCount());
        Assert.IsTrue(session.QueryOver<Article>().RowCount() > 0);
        session.Close();
    }
```

This (either the `Assert` or the `Debug`) gives the following exception:

```
Seguimiento de la pila de Result:   
en NHibernate.Impl.AbstractQueryImpl.UniqueElement(IList list)
en NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.UniqueResult[T]()
en NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.SingleOrDefault[U]()
en NHibernate.Criterion.QueryOver`1.NHibernate.IQueryOver<TRoot>.RowCount()
en MyCompany.Test.NHibernateTests.EncuentraArticulosTest() en ...\NHibernateTests.cs:línea 36
Mensaje de Result:  
El método de prueba MyCompany.Test.NHibernateTests.EncuentraArticulosTest produjo la excepción: 
NHibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this answer from Java's version (Hibernate):

[How to perform a non-polymorphic HQL query in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093025/how-to-perform-a-non-polymorphic-hql-query-in-hibernate?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This happens by design because your derived classes are base types.  This is classic object oriented polymorphism.

See this ticket if you really need to get only base class entities back.

[NHibernate: Load base class objects only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740666/nhibernate-load-base-class-objects-only)